What is this type of "compression" clamp called (that is used for fence posts or the like)?
Recently, I encountered a type of clamp whose name I do not know. It is similar to a compression clamp or a hose clamp. It is much better than a hose clamp at tightening fence posts (or pipes/rods) together than a hose clamp. I have attached a picture. What is the name? What kind of stores would carry it?


I'm not certain, but it looks like a modified sprinkler pipe clamp ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sprinkler+pipe+clamp&iax=images&ia=images

@jsotola I think that might be it. I've actually seen these in my work office for what looks like water pipes. Where would I get them? Would Home Depot have them?

what looks like water pipes that is probably the fire suppression sprinkler system

Based on @jsotola's suggestion, I found product pages that describe these as "loop hangers." Looks like they are used to hang pipes (e.g. sprinkler pipes) from ceilings. In my case I would need to buy an L-shaped machine screw instead of the strut that would typically hold these loops.

In my area of the US that is referred to as a Saddle Clamp.
